# I'm using htaccess to create pretty URLs, but they seem to be causing a facebook login error

Tags: .htaccess, facebook, oauth

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ pages.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Here is the error I receive when I try to login or out from this page:

`OAuthException: Error validating access token.`

This does not happen when I access the page directly at:

http://www.example.com/pages.php?a=4

Comment: You are not appending any of the values to the url..   Try changing [L] to [L,QSA]

Comment: As a side note, what exactly are you trying to acomplish with the rewrite rule?  e.g. what is a before and after url supposed to look like?

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC  in this specific case I'm just making a generic rule: so that `example.com/asdf/fancy` is the same as `example.com/qwerty/fancy`

Comment: And also, you should add that as an answer so I can vote it as correct. That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request:

Facebook passes the authentication back in the URL string, so that must include that during the rewrite..

Whenever you rewrite urls, you need to make sure it appends all submitted variables...  (QSA Flag)

Simply adding adding QSA will fix it:

```
[QSA,L]
```

Two great pages to check out:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Pretty much if your dealing with a common rewrite, either of those pages can answer almost any question you may have...
(the second link is all about rewrites)